# loading a URL to a div tag

Tags: php, ajax

Hi I need to load a url inside to a div tag using Ajax. This is the code I used.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    document.getElementById("Loading_Page").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}

  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","UserTypesPHP.php",true);

xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And this is how my UserTypesPHP.php looks like.

```
<?php

// Create connection
include('connectionPHP.php');


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 //Adding Student records
 if (!empty($_POST['UserTypeSubmit'])){ 


  $sqlstu1="INSERT INTO user_type(User_ID ,User_Name) VALUES('$_POST[UserTypeID]','$_POST[UserType]')";



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sqlstu1))
  {
die("<script>alert( \"Error: ". mysqli_error($con)."\");window.location.href='AdminUser.php';</script>");


  }

 else
 echo "<script>alert ('The lecture was recorded successfully');
 window.location.href=' AdminUser.php';
 </script>";


 }



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Im trying to redirect AdminUser.php to Loading_Page div. But this doesn't work out as expect. Please someone let me know the reason.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Scripts are not executed when inserted into `.innerHTML`. You need to create a script element explicitly.

Comment: You should redirect on a callback. put a callback and execute it when your content is loaded inside the div.

Comment: Typically you don't want to send `scripts` over AJAX calls, that's inefficient. You'll want to send just the HTML, or even just the data. In this case something like: `{ "result": [ "ok", { "message": "The lecture was recorded successfully", "redirect": "AdminUser.php" } ] }`

Comment: @Barmar: Could you please show me an example how I can do it.

Comment: Frits van Campen: do I need to put your code instead of wt I have used. But still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'success'){
      response(); 
    }
    //document.getElementById("Loading_Page").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }

  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","UserTypesPHP.php",true);

xmlhttp.send();
}
function response(){
     alert ('The lecture was recorded successfully');
     window.location.href=' AdminUser.php';
}
```

And on the php file:

```
   <?php

// Create connection
include('connectionPHP.php');


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 //Adding Student records
 if (!empty($_POST['UserTypeSubmit'])){ 


  $sqlstu1="INSERT INTO user_type(User_ID ,User_Name) VALUES('$_POST[UserTypeID]','$_POST[UserType]')";



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sqlstu1))
  {
die("<script>alert( \"Error: ". mysqli_error($con)."\");window.location.href='AdminUser.php';</script>");


  }

 else
 echo "success";


 }



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution. It assumes that if the response contains `<script>`, the entire response is a script -- it doesn't try to parse the script out of other HTML.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        if (/<script>/.test(xmlhttp.responseText)) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText.replace(/<\/?script.*?>/g, '')));
            document.getElementByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(script);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("Loading_Page").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```